# "Must had been like" correct grammar in the past continous?

Tags: grammar, tenses

Scenario:

- Person1: Two people were kissing in the elevator. I was staring at
  them for a minute until the lady yelled at me.
- Person2: The lady must
  had been thinking like "What a weirdo"

In this scenario, it's describing something that had already completed. Further it states the exact phrase what must have had running in her head at that exact time.

So, is it correct to say "must had been thinking like"?

English is not my first language. So it's confusing.

Comment: Where have you found these sentences? It's "must **have** been".

Comment: @fev I thought like "must have been" have a different meaning like "she must have been doing this for 10 years upto this very moment"? so it's past but continous? but I need something happened for a short period in the past but still it's finished or completed now. So, I used "Had"

Comment: [You cannot use "had" after "must"](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/must_1).

Comment: _Must had_ is not a valid construction. Also, _like_ is unnecessary here.

Comment: So the correct form would be "The lady must have been thinking "what a weirdo"" ?

Comment: Like is used colloquially as a [quotative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Like#As_a_colloquial_quotative) but I don't think that's the issue here, the main problem is "had" which is wrong.

Comment: Yes, that would be correct (except that _What_ needs a capital letter, as you gave it in your original version).